# Combine row_number() and string column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, row-number

I need to combine to a string column and the result of a `row_number()` calculation
into one column.

What I've got is column 1, containing strings and column 2, containing the `row_number()` result. Now I to combine both into one.

What's the way of this in Postgres? I figured that a simple `+` or `&` does not
work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself:

```
table.col || ' ' || row_number()...
```